# Django datetime not work as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to calculate and store date one year in the future if some field is True. But seems that datetime doesn't work as I expect. `date` field is populated correctly but `featured_to_date` field stay always empty in any case. Here is the model:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class Site(models.Model):
    ...
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured_to_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        if self.featured:
            oneyear = timedelta(days=365)
            featured_to_date = datetime.datetime.now() + oneyear
        super(Site, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You can remove your `if not self.id` logic by taking advantage of [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) on your `date` field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `self.featured_to_date`, not `featured_to_date`, like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if self.featured:
        oneyear = timedelta(days=365)
        self.featured_to_date = datetime.datetime.now() + oneyear
    super(Site, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So obviously but I simply didn't see it at all. Thanks girasquid!